# Logging to console for child loggers is enabled only after logging from root logger in python

Tags: python, logging

Take a look at this code:

```
import logging

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('TEST').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#logging.debug('message')

logging.getLogger().debug('message')
logging.getLogger('TEST').debug('message')
```

With the commented line `logging.debug('message')` when I run the script I don't see ANY log message in the console as I expect.
I expect to see two log messages from root and TEST loggers, but I see nothing.

But when I uncomment the line, I see three log messages as expected.

What is the problem?

P.S: My python version: 3.10.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't configure any handlers, and handlers are the things that output logging messages. The line

```
logging.debug('message')
```

does an implicit configuration of a handler (as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug), in the last paragraph) and so you get messages output. That last paragraph says:

> This function [meaning `logging.debug()`] (as well as `info()`, `warning()`, `error()` and `critical()`) will call basicConfig() if the root logger doesn’t have any handler attached.

See also the [advanced tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial), which talks about what roles loggers, handlers, filters and formatters play.